# Where can I see list of services registered in Kubernetes Discovery?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, discovery

In case of using eureka (+ Spring Boot) you can reach special endpoint where list of currently registered instances can be found. E.g.:
[image: Instances currently registered with Eureka]

Does Kubernetes service discovery have such endpoint or may be other mechanism to see all currently registered instances?
UPD: Does kubernetes api have any possibilities to do this, may be via kubectl?

Comment: try  `kubectl get svc` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve problem after a while.

1. Add endpoint in of your microservices. Example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/main/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples/kubernetes-hello-world-example/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/examples/HelloController.java)
2. Add roles to your kubernetes cluster:

> ```
> kind: ClusterRole
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> metadata:
>   namespace: yours
>   name: service-reader
> rules:
>   - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
>     resources: ["services"]
>     verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
>
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: ClusterRoleBinding
> metadata:
>   name: service-reader-pod
> subjects:
>   - kind: ServiceAccount
>     name: default
>     namespace: yours
> roleRef:
>   kind: ClusterRole
>   name: service-reader
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> ```

Answer (score 1):

No. Eureka is a service discovery AND registration system. The spring cloud implementation of service discovery on kubernetes only reads from the kubernetes api. You could probably get the information via kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has an HTTP-based API that you can interact with in many ways (e.g.: `kubectl`), of course you can use `curl` too.
Here's how: [Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)

If you are curious about your pods, you can do:

- `kubectl get pods` or `kubectl get pods -o json`
- `curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pods`

If you mean `services` (and their registered targets):

- `kubectl get services` or `kubectl services pods -o json`
- `curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/services`

Comment: No, not pods, I mean applications in pods which are registered in Kuber discovery

Comment: @Alex I see, I edited my answer, please check if it is what you need.